# How do I read all the arguments passed to a function that takes a variadic parameter of some type?

Tags: go, variadic-functions

```
func foo(x... int) {

//Do something with the arguments.

}
```

Function foo takes any number of arguments of a particular type. How do I read those arguments inside the function?

> I can do so when a **slice of int** is passed to the function foo but not if arguments are ***not*** passed as **a slice of int**.

Comment: [The spec.](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

Comment: I wanted to know how to read the arguments, I already know it supports variadic functions.

Comment: And the answer to that question - and many other places on SO and web search results for golang variadic functions - explain how to read the arguments.

Comment: Downvoted. Try searching on google first. There are numerous links explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can do so when a slice of int is passed to the function foo but not if arguments are not passed as a slice of int.

You can use "x" as a slice in both cases. The following should work regardless of the way you call the function:

```
for i, v := range x {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yup, see https://play.golang.org/p/rex_VLyI2c

Comment: Yeah it does work.